# How to detect when new markers have been added to the leaflet map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers, event-listener

May i ask how to I add a event listener to the map to detect when a marker has been added to the map?
In the docs, it says that we can use the "add" event, but how do I actually use it?
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker

I have tried:

```
map.on(marker,'add', function() { // Throws a error "marker is not defined"
    console.log('marker added')
}); 

map.on('add', function() { // doesn't do anything
    console.log('marker added')
});
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add` event detects when a *specific* marker is added to the map.

```
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]); // first, define a marker

marker.on('add', function() { // called when the specific marker is added to the map
    console.log('marker added');
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wLqcsb0L/

I think you may want [Leaflet's `layeradd` event on `L.Map`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-layeradd), which will fire when *any* layer is added to the map.